# yii pdfable outputting unwanted text

Tags: pdf, yii, pdf-generation, yii-extensions

I have managed to create pdf file using pdfable in Yii. The problem with the pdf document is it is including the main menu as list items which it should not. Where is this coming from and how can I stop it?

**controller**

```
$asaarea = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT distinct(asaarea) FROM `hdb`.`lookupcountry`")->queryAll();        

        $results = array();
        foreach ($asaarea as $key => $value) {
            $results[$value['asaarea']] = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT
                StartDATE,
                PROJECT,
                PROJCODE,
                PROJID,
                ActualEndDate,
                OFFICE,
                PERCENT,
                PERCENTPlanned,
                KM,
                KMPlanned,
                COUNTRY,
                AREA,
                PROJINFO
                FROM view_webprojectreport where asaarea = '" . $value['asaarea'] . "'")->queryAll();
        }


        $pdf = $this->createPdf();
        $pdf->setOptions(array('orientation'=>'Landscape',
                'margin-top'    => 5,
                'margin-right'  => 10,
                'margin-bottom' => 5,
                'margin-left'   => 10,
                )
            );
        $pdf->renderPage('print',array('results'=>$results));

        $pdf->send('ProjectReport_'.date('M-Y').'.pdf');
```

**print.php**

```
<head>
<style type='text/css'>

@media print{thead{display:table-header-group; margin-bottom:2px;}}
@page{margin-top:1cm;margin-left:1cm;margin-right:1cm;margin-bottom:1.5cm;}}

.odd {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E5F1F4;
}
.even {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F8F8F8;
}
table tbody tr:hover{
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 lightgreen;
}
table tbody tr{
    font-size:10pt;
}
body
{
  margin: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm;

}

.grey{
    background: lightgrey;
}

.center{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.size{
    font-size:15px;
}

table{
    padding-botton:30px;
}
thead{
    font-size:11px;
     font-weight: normal;
}

</style>
</head>
<!-- <body onload="window.print();window.close();">-->
<body>
<h1 class="grey center">Project Report</h1>
<table>
<?php 
$count = 0;
$class= null;
foreach($results as $key=>$data) {
?>

<tr class="grey size">
    <th colspan=12><?=$key ?></th>
</tr>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Actual End Date</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>%</th>
        <th>% Planned</th>
        <th>KM</th>
        <th>KM Planned</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th width="150">AREA</th>
        <th>PROJ INFO</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($data as $column=>$q) {   ?>

    <?php 
        $class = ($count % 2 === 0) ? 'odd' : 'even';
        $this->renderPartial('_report',array('data'=>$q,'class'=>$class));
        $count++;
    }
    ?>
</tbody>


<?php }
?>
</table>
</body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post this, so it's only a guess, but it's probably the menu from your layout file.

Pdfable renders each page like a regular Yii page - it's not like `renderPartial()`. So maybe you should create a layout specific for PDFs and configure this as layout file. For example you could create `views/layouts/pdf.php`:

```
<?php
// In the simplest case you only output $content here. But 
// you could also add a nice header to all your PDFs.
echo $content;
```

In your `print.php` you can then add this line on top.

```
<?php $this->layout = 'pdf'; ?>
```

Comment: i have done this but i get a blank page now. Reading `http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/493/how-to-setting-layouts-in-yii/` do I need to add anything in my controller. Currently I have `public $layout='//layouts/column2';`

Comment: got i working `<?php /* @var $this Controller */ ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<div class="span-19">
 <div id="content">
  <?php echo $content; ?>
 </div><!-- content -->
</div>
</html>`

Comment: However the text still gets cut off on each page below and bottom of new pages?